# SSLError Certificate verified failed

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape a website for information. I downloaded anacoda and uses python.

these are my code

```
   from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
   dibbsurl = 'https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/RFQ/RfqRecs.aspx?category=issue&TypeSrch=dt&Value=09-06-2017'
   uClient = uReq(dibbsurl)
```

the error below display while attempting to open up the connection to the url.

> > ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
```

I saw some solution for similar problem about double clicking the install certificate file. I did that but the error still persist. What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urllib` will raise an exception if it can't verify the server certificate. You could either use a custom ssl context in the `context` parameter, or use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and disable verification.

Using `urllib` with `ssl`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import ssl

context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
dibbsurl = 'https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/RFQ/RfqRecs.aspx?category=issue&TypeSrch=dt&Value=09-06-2017'
uClient = uReq(dibbsurl, context=context)
```

Using `requests`:

```
import requests

dibbsurl = 'https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/RFQ/RfqRecs.aspx?category=issue&TypeSrch=dt&Value=09-06-2017'
uClient = requests.get(dibbsurl, verify=False)
data = uClient.content
```